# How can I root my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet?

Tags: rooting, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

Lenovo doesn't provide updates for the Thinkpad Tablet any more. I'd like to install a custom ROM and therefore need root.

How can I root my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [**"debugfs automated root"**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1706588) works for the latest official ROM of the Thinkpad Tablet. Like most other root methods, you need to have the Android SDK (or at least `adb`) installed and must be able to connect `adb` to your Lenovo Thinkpad (Enable debug mode).

## Linux Users

1. Download the exploit [from the XDA Post.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1706588)
2. `unzip DebugfsRoot_Generic_v2.3.zip`
3. `adb push debugfs /data/local/`
4. `adb push su /data/local/`
5. `adb push debugfsinput /data/local/`
6. `adb shell mv /data/local/tmp /data/local/tmp.bak`
7. `adb shell ln -s /dev/block/mmcblk0p3 /data/local/tmp`
8. `adb reboot`
9. `adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/debugfs`
10. Now run the exploit: `adb shell "/data/local/debugfs -w /dev/block/mmcblk0p3 < /data/local/debugfsinput"`
11. Cleanup: `adb shell rm /data/local/tmp && adb shell mv /data/local/tmp.bak /data/local/tmp`
12. Install superuser: `adb install Superuser.apk`

## Windows

Just run the provided `RootDebugfs.bat`

Comment: Is this specific to that device, or kind of Generic for certain Android versions?

Comment: I believe that the exploit can be used on other devices too. But I cannot verify this of course. All I can say is that it worked for me with the latest stock version.  And this is the situation most people who want to root the TPT are in.

Comment: Hm, so I might give this a try with my Cat, before I return it due to its display error... Will take a look at the stuff if it does no harm when failing ;)

Comment: If you want to use the exploit method on anther device make sure to replace `/dev/block/mmcblk0p3` with the correct device node.

Comment: Good point. Which one is it? I mean, the "target partition" (recovery, system, data...)?

Comment: `/system` (or just follow the steps `RootDebugfs.bat` does).

Comment: Could you state specifically the version(s) this works on?

Comment: At least the latest stock ROM for XEU. But I am pretty sure that it will work on every up to date stock ROM (although I can not verify this, since I only own an XEU device).

Comment: Tnx @Flow! Will try it ASAP and report back.

Comment: Grmpf. `/system` here is not `/dev/...` but simply `ubi0_0` ([UBIFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBIFS)), so I better don't play with it I guess...