# How can I install CWM Recovery on my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

I want to install a custom ROM or use one of the many other features of Clockworkmod Recovery on my Thinkpad Tablet.

How can I install CWM Recovery on my Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet?

Comment: Is it rooted? And boot loader unlocked? :)

Comment: It is rooted now. This question is part 2 of my series of the thinkpad tablet. I am not sure if the boot loader is unlocked but it worked with just rooting. You can join the chat and tell my what you mean by "unlocked bootloader" if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Installing CWM Recovery

CWM Recovery for the Thinkpad Tablet can be [found on XDA.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1831161) You need [**root** on your Tablet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37322/how-can-i-root-my-lenovo-thinkpad-tablet-running-the-latest-official-stock-rom) to install CWM Recovery. Download the recovery image (`recovery.img`) and follow the instructions provided by the post. It basically comes down to pushing the image file on the sdcard and overwriting the boot partition.

### Push the recovery image to the sdcard

```
adb push recovery.img /mnt/sdcard/
```

### Get root

```
adb shell
su
```

### Remount `/system` and backup `install-recovery.sh` (optional)

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
mv /system/etc/install-recovery.sh /system/etc/install-recovery.sh.backup
```

### Overwrite the boot partition

```
dd if=/mnt/sdcard/recovery.img of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p1
```

## Entering/Booting CWM Recovery on the Thinkpad Tablet

1. Shut down your Thinkpad Tablet
2. Press the power button until the Tablet vibrates
3. Keep pressing and releasing the *volume up* button until you see `Booting Recovery Kernel Image` in the upper left corner. It's all about timing of when the *volume up* button is pressed. That's why it's a good idea to just keep on pressing and releasing the button until the message appears.

Comment: I got the general instructions from XDA before I found your answer, but your section on "Entering/Booting CWM Recovery on the Thinkpad Tablet" was where I got stuck, and so that was the most helpful part of your answer for me.